# Redrawing the cocoa app's main window when clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sendmessage

I made an Mac OS X cocoa app, and when I click the red button the main window disappears.

[image]

However, when I clicked the icon in dock, it doesn't show the main window anymore.

[image]

What's wrong? How do i redraw the main window by catching what message?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this in your application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender {
    //show your window here
    return NO;
}
```